# Close menu when clicked outside of it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the Slide and Push Menus from codrops (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/) and it works fine but I want that the menu closes once you click outside of the menu. You can find the Html, css and Javascript on the site.

I read through a lot of similar stackoverflow threads but can't make it work.

It would be awesome if someone could help me !

Comment: One approach would be to add a click event listener to the `document` and check whether `event.target` is the menu or not and close the menu if not.

Answer (score 2):

As @Xufox commented before in the question. An approach like this:

```
function closemenu(e) {
    example = document.getElementById('example');
    if (e.target !== example) {
        example.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
document.addEventListener('click', closemenu);
```

You should bind this in the document or window as described in comments as a better way.. =)

[Live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/h8fzhhd2/2/)

Hope it helps. Nice coding !

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't make it work for some reason. It would be great if you could provide an example for the code of the website